# Android mobile usage history NetworkStatsManager

Tags: java, android, android-trafficstats, networkstatsmanager

I'm making an App for Android 6.0 and I want to use the new class NetworkStatsManager for getting mobile data usage.

I added all permission I need in manifest and require the permission runtime.

When I call the method:

```
bucket = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI, "", fromDate.getTime(), toDate.getTime());
```

return the right value for WIFI usage.

But if i replace TYPE_WIFI with TYPE_MOBILE the result is always 0.

```
    NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = null;
    try {
        bucket = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "", fromDate.getTime(), toDate.getTime());

        if(bucket == null){
            Log.i("Info", "Error");
        }else{
            Log.i("Info", "Total: " + (bucket.getRxBytes() + bucket.getTxBytes()));
        }

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution of this problem with hidden APIs ([android statistic 3g traffic for each APP, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613402/android-statistic-3g-traffic-for-each-app-how)) and when trying to retrieve mobile data usage information with TYPE_MOBILE  was necessary to inform the SubscriberID, unlike when I tryed to get information TYPE WIFI.

Try this code

```
    TelephonyManager  tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String subscriberID = tm.getSubscriberId();

    NetworkStats networkStatsByApp = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, subscriberID, start, end, uid);
```

So when you are using TYPE_MOBILE, it's necessary to you use a valid subscriberID.

Comment: Please do not just post code as an answer...at least explain your answer/code a little bit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added more informations about the solution.

Comment: Cool stuff @EMIDIOOLIVEIRA :)

Comment: Is there any chance to split mobile stats to home and roaming network?

Comment: i am getting still zero when using this code  public long getAllRxBytesMobile1(Context context) {
        NetworkStats.Bucket bucket;
        try {
            bucket = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                    getSubscriberId(context, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE),
                    0,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            return -1;
        }
        return bucket.getRxBytes();
    }

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi have you got the solutiions?

Comment: @NarenderReddy my answer could be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55891812/7090731

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to the accepted answer, I would also like to point out that in the following code,

```
TelephonyManager  tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String subscriberID = tm.getSubscriberId(); //subscriberID is usually the IMSI number (for GSM phones)
```

`TelephonyManager  tm` contains the information about the default telephony service (SIM card) that is being used for making calls. So, if you are using a phone with Dual SIM cards and SIM 1 is being used for calls and SIM 2 is being used for Data, then `TelephonyManager  tm` will hold information about SIM 1 and in your use case, where you are using `NetworkStatsManager` for getting Data usage stats, SIM 1 info will be of no use as it is not being used for consuming Data. So, you somehow need to fetch the `TelephonyManager` for SIM 2 so that you can use the correct subscriber Id of SIM 2 in `networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice()` to get the mobile data usage stats. So, how do you do this?

One way that I figured out is like this:

```
public void subscriberIdsOfDualSim(){
    SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);
    //we'll now get a List of information of active SIM cards
    //for example, if there are 2 SIM slots and both the slots have 1 SIM card each, then the List size will be 2
    List<SubscriptionInfo> activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : activeSubscriptionInfoList) {
        //loop through the SIM card info
        //if there are 2 SIM cards, then we'll try to print the subscriberId of each of the SIM cards
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            //the following createForSubscriptionId() is available from API 24 :(
            TelephonyManager manager1=manager.createForSubscriptionId(subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId());
            String operatorName=manager1.getNetworkOperatorName();
            String subscriberId=manager1.getSubscriberId(); //use this subscriberId to do NetworkStatsManager stuff
            System.out.println("subscriberIdsOfDualSim: Carrier Name: "+operatorName+", subscriber id: "+subscriberId);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I have used `createForSubscriptionId()` method. One limitation of this method is that it can be used from API 24 (Android 7.0 Nougat) only.

So, if you are using both SIM 1 and SIM 2 for data consumption, then you can get the data usage info for each of the SIM cards by providing the `subscriberId` of each of them to `networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice()`. But, if you want to get correct mobile data consumption (both SIM 1 and SIM 2 inclusive) and you want to support phones below Nougat, then the good old `getMobileRxBytes()` and `getMobileTxBytes()` methods in `TrafficStats` class is what you may have to use.

Comment: Another limitation is that from API 28 (app targetting it), getSubscriberId() returns null, or an exception if targetting API 29!

Answer (score 0):

Another follow up to the accepted answer and @Nandan, it's possible to obtain subscriber ids of both SIM cards using below code

```
SubscriptionManager subman = (SubscriptionManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
TelephonyManager telman = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

List<SubscriptionInfo> li = subman.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

for(SubscriptionInfo info : li){
    int sid = info.getSubscriptionId(); //not the id we want

    try{
        Class c = Class.forName("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");
        Method m = c.getMethod("getSubscriberId", new Class[]{int.class});
        Object o = m.invoke(telman, new Object[]{sid});

        String subid = (String)o;  //id we want
        Log.i("SubscriptionId", subid);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

}
```

Credit to answer link https://stackoverflow.com/a/38071705/9038181